# Cannot start a program with parameters

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I am having problems running a program with parameters. My batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off

set selfdir=%~dp0
set conf="%temp%\dosbox.%random%.conf"
set dosbox="%selfdir%dosbox.exe"

:: Other code

cmd /c %dosbox% --userconf %conf%

:: Other code
```

This fails with the error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Substituting `cmd /c` with `start /wait` complains about a missing '--userconf', and putting nothing in its place causes the program to start without the arguments.

EDIT: `%dosbox%` holds the location to the DOSBox executable.

How can I correct this problem?

Comment: Please show the output of `echo %dosbox%` .

Comment: `%dosbox%` is effectively `%~dp0dosbox.exe`. For the folder I'm running it from, it is `C:\turboc\dosbox.exe`

Comment: Looks good. And `echo cmd /c %dosbox% --userconf %conf%` ?

Comment: comment out `@echo off` so you can see what is actually being executed? Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding quotation marks `""` should do the trick:

```
cmd /c "%dosbox% --userconf %conf%"
```

Comment: @Endoro: And that's obvious, because...?

Comment: You are right and I'm wrong, `"%dosbox% --userconf %conf%"` doesn't work, but `cmd /c "%dosbox% --userconf %conf%"` works, sorry.